# How to change Header in WebClient

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to upload images to ImageShack using the API. I think they require the form to be `multipart/form-data`. I tried to do the below ...

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
...
var fs = new FileStream(@"filepath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
data.Add("fileupload", encoded);
...
byte[] output = wc.UploadValues("http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php ", "POST", data);
```

but got

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=The Content-Type header cannot be changed from its default value for this request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
       at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
       at WpfApplication1.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.Upload() in D:\tmp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs:line 61
       at WpfApplication1.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.<.ctor>b__1() in D:\tmp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs:line 18
       at MvvmFoundation.Wpf.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at WpfApplication1.App.Main() in D:\tmp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Whats wrong or how can i change headers in the WebClient then?

Comment: This is more than headers. This means packaging the body in a very specific way that UploadValues isn't able to process. You may need to transform it and send the body 'byte[]' manually. Which is hard. Or obtain a component to do it for you. Or ask if you can just send the file body as the payload.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you can not set Content-type with WebClient.UploadValues method. You could set Content-type with WebClient.UploadData method

Use something like,

```
Client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
Client.UploadData("http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes("{\"Data\": \"Test\"}"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this -- I was using UploadString with no dice.  I can't believe the docs; If I wanted to spend time doing trial and error or consulting others, I'd be a unix programmer!

Comment: @GerardONeill - I was able to call `Client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "appliction/json") using `UploadString(string, string)` and sending the data as the second parameter - I think the issue is with `UploadValues` as in your question.

Comment: 3 years later and this was still a mad helpful answer, +1 son.

Comment: 10 years later!

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9w7b4fz7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), WebException is thrown when:

> The Content-type header is not a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: I saw that but i am using "multipart/form-data"? ... oh is NOT icic, but how can i change the content type then?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can. From the documentation, looks like "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is the only acceptable value.