# How do I to change Header of WebClient class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to change Header of WebClient but it always throws an exception

`The Content-Type header cannot be changed from its default value for this request`

and I don't know how to solve it.

How could I fix it ?

```
//Webclient do the post to server.
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

//Header
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1";
```

Comment: What action are you performing using that `WebClient`? Are you attempting to `DownloadFile()`, `UploadFile()` etc?

Comment: @haim770 `wc.UploadValues(uri, "POST", NameValueCollection);`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3865193/1625737, then

Comment: @haim770 the `wc.UploadData` does not works with `NameValueCollection`